# How can I create a Prisma Enum that is a string and begins with a digit? ie: `19-20` (school year)?

Tags: typescript, enums, prisma

When Migrating to Prisma I created an enum of:

```js
enum SchoolYear {
  SY18_19 @map("18-19")
  SY19_20 @map("19-20")
  SY20_21 @map("20-21")
  SY21_22 @map("21-22")
  SY22_23 @map("22-23")
  SY23_24 @map("23-24")
  SY24_25 @map("24-25")
  SY25_26 @map("25-26")
  SY26_27 @map("26-27")
  SY27_28 @map("27-28")
  SY28_29 @map("28-29")
  SY29_30 @map("29-30")
  SY30_31 @map("30-31")
  SY31_32 @map("31-32")
  @@map("school_year")
}
```

Which lead to having issues where our code still passed a string in instead of using the enum
I tried to make it a string type but then get this error:

`Error converting field "schoolYear" of expected non-nullable type "String", found incompatible value of "18-19".`

Enums can't start with a number which seems to be the blocker here.
My two options are: use the Enum

```js
 await prisma.term.create({
    data: {
      schoolYear: SchoolYear.SY18_19
    },
  })
```

Or Prepend a `SY` on all the string values

```js
 await prisma.term.create({
    data: {
      schoolYear: 'SY18_19', // this will map to `18-19` in the database by Prisma
    },
  })
```

What I would like to do is keep it the same.

```js
 await prisma.term.create({
    data: {
      schoolYear: '18-19'
    },
  })
```

Is there any way to manage this?

Then the additional problem is that the value I get back from Prisma is `SY19_18`, however I want only the digits and the dash: `18-19`.